# Intersection of clopen sets that contain x is the connected component of x (if X is compact)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space, $x\in X $, $C$ is a connected component of $x$.

Define $A$ to be the intersection of all the open-and-closed sets that contain $x$ (also called the *pseudo-component* sometimes).

I wish to show that $A=C$, if $X$ is also compact (without it I think there is a counter-example).

Obviously $C$ is contained in $A$ (always) since any clopen set that contains $x$ contains $C$.
Also, $A$ is closed in $X$ so if $X$ is compact, $A$ is also compact. Not sure on how to proceed (tried supposing that $A$ is not contained in $C$ and getting a cover of $A$, doesn't seem to work).

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @LeeMosher Could you elaborate, please? I don't understand why is it a counter example (seems like still A=C).

Comment: FYI my comment was wrong and I deleted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not work without the assumption that $X$ is **normal**. For a counterexample, consider the

> $$**\textbf{sequence with two limits}**$$
>   Let $X=\{0,0'\}\cup\{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $\{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is discrete and a neighborhood of $0$ or $0'$ is a set containing almost all of the points $1/n$. This space is compact but not normal, and $\{0,0'\}$ is the quasi-component of $0$ but is not connected.

If we assume that your $X$ is normal, then we can prove that $A$ is connected:
Assume $A$ splits into two components $B,D$. Since $A$ is closed, $B$ and $D$ are both closed, so **if $X$ is normal** there are disjoint open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ around $B$ and $D$, respectively. The open sets $U$ and $V$ cover the intersection of all clopen neighborhoods of $A$, so **if $X$ is compact**, there must exist a finite number of clopen sets around $A$, say $A_1,\dots,A_n$ such that $U\cup V$ covers $K=\bigcap_1^n A_i$. Can you finish the proof from here?

*(If you want to see the solution, hover over the shaded area below)*

> Note that $K$ is clopen. We can assume that $x\in U$. It is not difficult to see that $K\cap U$ is clopen and does not contain all of $A$, contradicting the definition of $A$.