# The connected component containing $a$ is the subset of the intersection of clopen sets containing $a$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space and $a \in X$. Let $\Gamma_a$ be the collection of all clopen sets in $X$ that contain $a$. Let $C$ be the connected component of $X$ that contains $a$.

I'm trying to prove a result mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438160/intersection-of-clopen-sets-that-contain-x-is-the-connected-component-of-x-if-x) thread. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> **Theorem:** If $A \in \Gamma_a$ then $C \subset A$. This implies $C \subset\bigcap \Gamma_a$.

**Proof:** Let $\Lambda_a$ be the collection of all connected subsets of $X$ that contain $a$. Then $C = \bigcup \Lambda_a$. Fix $A \in \Gamma_a$ and $B \in \Lambda_a$. Then $\{B \cap A, B \cap A^c\}$ is a partition of $B$ where $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A^c$ are both clopen in $B$. Then either $B \cap A = \emptyset$ or $B \cap A^c = \emptyset$. Because $a \in A \cap B$. Then $B \subset A$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it can be simplified. You do not need the collection $\Lambda_a$. Simply take $C$ (which is by the way, also a member of $\Lambda_a$) instead of an arbitrary $B \in \Lambda_a$.

The intersection of all clopen sets in $X$ that contain $a$ is known as the *quasi-component of $a$*. You proved the well-known theorem that the component of a point $a \in X$ is always contained in its quasi-component.

Quasi-components and components [coincide for compact Hausdorff spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3411400).